# how to handle events on a global object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

Currently, I defined a function in which some events are placed. These events should be in global scope.
When a specific event (something like `connection` event) happens in the application, this function, `addWebrtcEvent`, will be called.

```js
function addWebrtcEvent(id) {
    window['peer_' + id] = peers[id]['cnnObj'];


    window['peer_' + id].on('stream', stream => {
        console.log('got remote stream');
    });

    window['peer_' + id].on('data', data => {
        console.log('got remote data');
    });

    window['peer_' + id].on('track', (track, stream) => {});
    window['peer_' + id].on('close', () => {});
    window['peer_' + id].on('error', (err) => {})
}
```

Is there anyway to define a global object and place these events somehow in it and not use the global window variable?

Thanks

Comment: but the global scope is the window object?

Comment: Why do you need it anyway, when you already have global `peers`?

Comment: @ trincot, At first `peers[id]['cnnObj']` is null and after `connection` established it stores the connection object. on this "connection object" events are defined. so it is not possible to define events on `peers` object in first time.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Sorry, I'm not sure about that. but I think window object is accessible in global scope(?)